# Lambda where Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, where-clause

I want to get the Id, but i only have the Name.
My code looks like this:

```
var comments = new List<Comments>
        {
            new Comments{
                CommunityId = community.FirstOrDefault(comid => comid.IdCommunity.Where(comid.CommunityName == "TestCommunity")),
            }
        };
```

Comments is a class:

```
public class Comments
{
    public int IdComment { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int CommunityId { get; set; }
}
```

Community as well:

```
public class Community
{
    public int IdCommunity { get; set; }
    public string CommunityName { get; set; }
    public Pictures Picture { get; set; }
}
```

But the statement `where` isn't existing in this scenario in C#.

Comment: Define *isn't accepted*. An error while compiling? You have `using System.Linq;` sitting on top?

Comment: can you provide, what is community?

Comment: `Where` returns a collection, but `FirstOrDefault` requires a `bool`. You'll probably want to use either `Any` instead of `Where` or chain the `FirstOrDefault` _after_ the `Where`. Precisely which depends on what `community` and `comid` is.

Comment: @PatrickHofman yes i have definded using SystemLinq

Comment: @Abion47 okay my fault, i will update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you work with linq try to simplify logic first, and break it on steps.
So first, you need to find all elements with CommunityName, Where statement will help with it:

```
var commList = community.Where(com => com.CommunityName == "TestCommunity");
```

Now in commList we got them. Second you need new array (IEnumerable) with Ids:

```
rawIds = commList.Select(x=>x.IdCommunity);
```

Thats it. Your next step is taking one record, first:

```
rawId = rawIds.First();
```

Now you have raw id, raw because it could be null. You need to check it for Null:

```
int Id;
if(rawId==null)
    Id = -1;
else
    Id = Convert.ToInt32(rawId);
```

The record above could be simplify:

```
int Id = rawId == null? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(rawId);
```

And now just join all linqs step by step:

```
rawId = community.Where(com => com.CommunityName == "TestCommunity").Select(com => com.IdCommunity).First();
int id = rawId == null ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(rawId);
```

Comment: Guys, when you hit -1, at least leave a comment why. This code work 100%, and it is an answer for a question.

Comment: Thanks, it works well.

Comment: It wasn't me, but my guess would be that this answer is a code dump with no explanation as to what you changed to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var comments = new List<Comments>
        {
            new Comments{
                CommunityId = community.FirstOrDefault(comid => comid.CommunityName == "TestCommunity")?.IdCommunity, //CommunityId should be nullable
            }
        };
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I'm struggeling with the '?' the error I got was cannot convert 'int?' to 'int' so i removed the question-mark and it worked.

Comment: @Rikvola The `?` is for checking if the `FirstOrDefault` returns null, which it will if none of the elements in `community` match the condition. If it does return null, then this code will throw an exception without the `?`. With the `?`, however, the entire line has a possibility of returning null, which means that `CommunityId` must be a Nullable int, or `int?`. Alternatively, you can use a ternary operator to check if the line returns null and, if so, have it return a default value instead, like `-1` for example.